# Using inertiajs and vue 3 scroll to an element after first visit page loading

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, inertiajs

i am trying to scroll into a specific element on the page after the first visit page loading is finished and it works but sadly it scrolls back immediately to the top of the page because of the preserveScroll feature included in inertiajs
how can i stop this behavior from re-scrolling back to the top ?

i tried to listen on all kinds on events in inertia but no luck the scroll keeps happening before the check on the preserveScroll value
i tried also using the scroll inside the onMounted hook but also no luck

Comment: I'm only guessing but if you can stopPropagation() on the inertiajs event, it might stop the bubbling up of the scroll.  But you need to find the object that does the scroll in the first place.  Again, this is only a guess and I have never worked with inertiajs.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.